# Problem in SQL SERVER 2008 Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I Synchronized a database from one server to another server by using Replication... Server1 is Publisher and Server2 is Subscriber. I have created a table in that database in both the servers. when i added a data into that table,It will also reflected in server2 also... Its Working Properly...
but now i dont want to create that table in both the servers... When i created a table in Server1(Publisher) then it should automatically create in Server2 also....That i want to create any one of the server and it have to create another database in another server......

is this possible? If so, how shall i do this?
Can any one tell me the Solution of this?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: you will get better answers on ServerFault for this.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Replication is specific to an object, not to the entire database.

If you want it to replicate tables, you will have to place a trigger on the source database SysObjects table and each time a new table is added you can run `EXEC sp_addarticle` with the appropriate parameters

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will check and let you know!!!! :-)